# Custom management command console output to log file in Django

Tags: python, django, logging, command, tornado

I have a custom management command which starts a Tornado loop in order to listen to websocket events. That loops writes its output to the console, which i want to redirect to a log file. I read the Django Docs about [Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), but still have no clue how to do it.

The relevent bits of code of my command which is based on [sockjs-tornado](https://github.com/MrJoes/sockjs-tornado):

```
from tornado import web, ioloop
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: you could redirect output when you start your command `python manage.py your_command >> a_log_file.log`

Comment: You can also use [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) to redirect output to stdout and to the log file.

Comment: You might be able to get away with something like: `import sys; sys.stdout = open('mylog', 'a')` before starting it, but it's a bit hacky. The proper way would be to manipulate the file descriptors at a lower level.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @dm03514: i tried that, but id doesn't catch the output of the ioloop. Also, the output is not appended in realtime, but after the process finished.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev: tee looks very interesting!

Comment: @Aya: i will try that approach too.